# Efficiently querying a huge time series table for one row every 15 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, group-by, postgresql-performance

I have two tables, `conttagtable` (t) and `contfloattable` (cf).  T has about 43k rows. CF has over 9 billion.

I created an index on both tables on the `tagindex` column on both tables.  This column can be thought of as a unique identifier for `conttagtable` and as a foreign key into `conttagtable` for `confloattable`. I didn't explicitly create a PK or foreign key on either table relating to the other, although this data is logically related by the `tagindex` column on both tables as if `conttagtable.tagindex` were a `PRIMARY KEY` and `contfloattable.tagindex` where a `FOREIGN KEY (tagindex) REFERENCES conttagtable(tagindex)`. The data came from a microsoft access dump and I didn't know if I could trust tagindex to be unique, so "uniqueness" is not enforced.

The data itself is extremely large.

I need to obtain single arbitrarily selected row from `contfloattable` for each 15-minute `contfloattable.dateandtime` interval for each `conttagtable.tagid`. So, if the `contfloattable` for a given `tagid` has 4000 samples spanning 30 minutes, I need a sample from the 0-14 minute range and a sample from the 15-30 minute range. Any one sample within the 15 minute range is acceptable; 1st, last, random, whatever.

In a nutshell, I need to get a sample every 15 minutes but only one sample per t.tagname. The samples right now are recorded every 5 seconds and the data spans two years.  This is a big data problem and way over my head in terms of sql.  All of the time interval solutions I have tried from googling or searching on SO have yielded query times that are so long that they are not practical.

- Are my indexes sufficient for a fast join? (they appear to be when leaving out the time interval part)
- Would I benefit by the addition of any other indexes?
- What's the best/fastest query that accomplish the above goals?

Here's an SQLFiddle containing the schema and some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c7d2f/2

Schema:

```
        Table "public.conttagtable" (t)
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers
-------------+---------+-----------
 tagname     | text    |
 tagindex    | integer |
 tagtype     | integer |
 tagdatatype | integer |
Indexes:
    "tagindex" btree (tagindex)


             Table "public.contfloattable" (CF)
   Column    |            Type             | Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 dateandtime | timestamp without time zone |
 millitm     | integer                     |
 tagindex    | integer                     |
 Val         | double precision            |
 status      | text                        |
 marker      | text                        |
Indexes:
    "tagindex_contfloat" btree (tagindex)
```

The output i'd like to see is something like this:

```
cf.dateandtime      |cf."Val"|cf.status|t.tagname
--------------------------------------------------
2012-11-16 00:00:02  45       S         SuperAlpha
2012-11-16 00:00:02  45       S         SuperBeta
2012-11-16 00:00:02  45       S         SuperGamma
2012-11-16 00:00:02  45       S         SuperDelta
2012-11-16 00:15:02  45       S         SuperAlpha
2012-11-16 00:15:02  45       S         SuperBeta
2012-11-16 00:15:02  45       S         SuperGamma
2012-11-16 00:15:02  45       S         SuperDelta
2012-11-16 00:30:02  45       S         SuperAlpha
2012-11-16 00:30:02  45       S         SuperBeta
2012-11-16 00:30:02  45       S         SuperGamma
2012-11-16 00:30:02  45       S         SuperDelta
2012-11-16 00:45:02  42       S         SuperAlpha
```

...etc etc...

As suggested by Clodoaldo, this is my latest attempt, any suggestions to speed it up?

```
with i as (
    select cf.tagindex, min(dateandtime) dateandtime
    from contfloattable cf
    group by
        floor(extract(epoch from dateandtime) / 60 / 15),
        cf.tagindex
)
select cf.dateandtime, cf."Val", cf.status, t.tagname
from
    contfloattable cf
    inner join
    conttagtable t on cf.tagindex = t.tagindex
    inner join
    i on i.tagindex = cf.tagindex and i.dateandtime = cf.dateandtime
order by floor(extract(epoch from cf.dateandtime) / 60 / 15), cf.tagindex
```

Query plan from the above: http://explain.depesz.com/s/loR

Comment: a single row for each {t.tagname, 15 min interval}.  The tagname is just a column that describes a device.  The device in this case is a sensor that recorded a value at a point in time.  I'm being asked to provide a discrete value for each device (tagname) every 15 minutes.

Comment: I don't really understand your query requirements. There are, on average, about 200,000 `contfloattable` records for each `conttagtable` record. How do you get this down to just one output-row for each `conttagtable.tagname`?

Comment: @ruakh, yes,there are a lot of records.  Sorry for the confusing explanation.  Let's say I have 10 tagnames and each tagname records a value every 5 seconds.  I only want 1 of those recorded values, plucked from a 15 min interval.  So for a time value of 01:00:00, i'd see 10 rows.  If i wanted two time values, 01:00:00 and 01:15:00, i'd see 20 rows.  One row for each tagname for each 15 min interval.  Is that more clear?

Comment: @user1598390 I don't have all of the ways i've tried, i'll post one of the ways i've tried above.

Comment: @sneaky-wombat Please put the queries you have tried in the question and format it.

Comment: also please provide the output of the explain analyze

Comment: I added an example of what i have tried.  It's a 5 min interval, which isn't want I need, but I thought if I could get it to work quickly, i could then change it to the proper time interval of 15 mins.

Comment: Out of the 180 samples per 15 minute segment, how do you want to pick the sample to use? Do you need to aggregate/combine them in any way? Pick the "best"? Pick a random one? Pick the 1st or last in the time window?

Comment: @CraigRinger, great question. I was told that it doesn't matter. Max, min, avg, rand. Whatever.

Comment: Here's the one I've been messing around with. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c7d2f/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 15 minutes intervals:

```
with i as (
    select cf.tagindex, min(dateandtime) dateandtime
    from contfloattable cf
    group by
        floor(extract(epoch from dateandtime) / 60 / 15),
        cf.tagindex
)
select cf.dateandtime, cf."Val", cf.status, t.tagname
from
    contfloattable cf
    inner join
    conttagtable t on cf.tagindex = t.tagindex
    inner join
    i on i.tagindex = cf.tagindex and i.dateandtime = cf.dateandtime
order by cf.dateandtime, t.tagname
```

Show the explain output for this query (if it works) so we can try to optimize. You can post it in this answer.

**Explain Output**

```
"Sort  (cost=15102462177.06..15263487805.24 rows=64410251271 width=57)"
"  Sort Key: cf.dateandtime, t.tagname"
"  CTE i"
"    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=49093252.56..49481978.32 rows=19436288 width=12)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..38528881.68 rows=1408582784 width=12)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=270117658.06..1067549320.69 rows=64410251271 width=57)"
"        Hash Cond: (cf.tagindex = t.tagindex)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=270117116.39..298434544.23 rows=1408582784 width=25)"
"              Merge Cond: ((i.tagindex = cf.tagindex) AND (i.dateandtime = cf.dateandtime))"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=2741707.02..2790297.74 rows=19436288 width=12)"
"                    Sort Key: i.tagindex, i.dateandtime"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on i  (cost=0.00..388725.76 rows=19436288 width=12)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=267375409.37..274418323.29 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=267375409.37..270896866.33 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"                          Sort Key: cf.tagindex, cf.dateandtime"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..24443053.84 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=335.74..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on conttagtable t  (cost=0.00..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
```

It looks like you need this index:

```
create index cf_tag_datetime on contfloattable (tagindex, dateandtime)
```

Run `analyze` after creating it. Now notice that any index on a big table will have a significant performance impact on data changes (insert etc) as it will have to be updated at each change.

**Update**

I added the cf_tag_datetime index (tagindex,dateandtime) and here's the new explain:

```
"Sort  (cost=15349296514.90..15512953953.25 rows=65462975340 width=57)"
"  Sort Key: cf.dateandtime, t.tagname"
"  CTE i"
"    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=49093252.56..49490287.76 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..38528881.68 rows=1408582784 width=12)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=270179293.86..1078141313.22 rows=65462975340 width=57)"
"        Hash Cond: (cf.tagindex = t.tagindex)"
"        ->  Merge Join  (cost=270178752.20..298499296.08 rows=1408582784 width=25)"
"              Merge Cond: ((i.tagindex = cf.tagindex) AND (i.dateandtime = cf.dateandtime))"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=2803342.82..2852972.22 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"                    Sort Key: i.tagindex, i.dateandtime"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on i  (cost=0.00..397035.20 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=267375409.37..274418323.29 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=267375409.37..270896866.33 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"                          Sort Key: cf.tagindex, cf.dateandtime"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..24443053.84 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=335.74..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on conttagtable t  (cost=0.00..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
```

It seems to have gone up in time :(  However, if I remove the order by clause (not exactly what i need, but would work), this is what happens, big reduction:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=319669581.62..1127631600.98 rows=65462975340 width=57)"
"  Hash Cond: (cf.tagindex = t.tagindex)"
"  CTE i"
"    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=49093252.56..49490287.76 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..38528881.68 rows=1408582784 width=12)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=270178752.20..298499296.08 rows=1408582784 width=25)"
"        Merge Cond: ((i.tagindex = cf.tagindex) AND (i.dateandtime = cf.dateandtime))"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=2803342.82..2852972.22 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"              Sort Key: i.tagindex, i.dateandtime"
"              ->  CTE Scan on i  (cost=0.00..397035.20 rows=19851760 width=12)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=267375409.37..274418323.29 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=267375409.37..270896866.33 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"                    Sort Key: cf.tagindex, cf.dateandtime"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on contfloattable cf  (cost=0.00..24443053.84 rows=1408582784 width=21)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=335.74..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on conttagtable t  (cost=0.00..335.74 rows=16474 width=44)"
```

I have not yet tried this index...will do so though. standby.

Now looking at it again I think the inverse index could be even better as it can be used not only in the `Merge Join` but also in the final `Sort`:

```
create index cf_tag_datetime on contfloattable (dateandtime, tagindex)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works great over a small dataset (I pulled some data from the larger set to experiment on).  Any ideas on how to reduce the query times on it? I posted a new explain above.

Comment: @SneakyWombat I posted the index I suspect you need.

Comment: is that index in addition to the existing one?  I assume yes.  I started the create process for that index but it will probably take two hours to finish (or more).  Standby, and thanks for the help.

Comment: @SneakyWombat I suspect that the existing index on cf.tagindex alone will not be used by the planner as that column's cardinality is very low. So you can test dropping it.

Comment: Is that index suggestion based on this output from explain? "Sort Key: cf.tagindex, cf.dateandtime"?  I see it twice in there and it's quite expensive.

Comment: Would adding a PK to these tables help at all?  Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: i see you added another index - just to be clear, is that in addition to the previous or instead of the previous suggestion?

Comment: @SneakyWombat In instead. Just as a test suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another formulation. I'll be quite curious to see how it scales on the full data set. Create this index first:

```
CREATE INDEX contfloattable_tag_and_timeseg
ON contfloattable(tagindex, (floor(extract(epoch FROM dateandtime) / 60 / 15) ));
```

then run this with as much `work_mem` as you can afford:

```
SELECT 
  (first_value(x) OVER (PARTITION BY x.tagindex, floor(extract(epoch FROM x.dateandtime) / 60 / 15))).*,
  (SELECT t.tagname FROM conttagtable t WHERE t.tagindex = x.tagindex) AS tagname
FROM contfloattable x ORDER BY dateandtime, tagname;
```

*Sneaky Wombat*: Explain from above sql on the full data set (without suggested index): http://explain.depesz.com/s/kGo

Alternately, here's one where only one sequential pass across `contfloattable` should be required, with values collected into a tuplestore that's then `JOIN`ed against to get the tag name. It requires lots of `work_mem`:

```
SELECT cf.dateandtime, cf.dataVal, cf.status, t.tagname
FROM 
  (
    SELECT (first_value(x) OVER (PARTITION BY x.tagindex, floor(extract(epoch FROM x.dateandtime) / 60 / 15))).*
    FROM contfloattable x
  ) cf
  INNER JOIN
  conttagtable t ON cf.tagindex = t.tagindex
ORDER BY cf.dateandtime, t.tagname;
```

*Sneaky Wombat*: Explain from above sql on the full data set (without suggested index): http://explain.depesz.com/s/57q

If it works you'll want to throw as much `work_mem` as you can afford at the query. You haven't mentioned your system's RAM, but you'll want a decent chunk of it; try:

```
SET work_mem = '500MB';
```

... or more if you have at least 4GB of RAM and are on a 64-bit CPU. Again, I'd be really interested to see how it works on the full data set.

BTW, for correctness of these queries I'd advise you to `ALTER TABLE conttagtable ADD PRIMARY KEY (tagindex);` then `DROP INDEX t_tagindex;`. It'll take some time as it'll be building a unique index. Most of the queries mentioned here are assuming that `t.tagindex` is unique in `conttagtable`, and that really should be enforced. The unique index can be used for additional optimisations that the old non-unique `t_tagindex` cannot, and it produces much better statistics estimates.

Also, when comparing query plans, note that `cost` isn't necessarily strictly proportional to real-world execution time. If the estimates are good then it should roughly correlate, but the estimates are only that. Sometimes you'll see a high-cost plan execute faster than a supposedly low-cost plan due to things like bad rowcount estimates or index selectivity estimates, limitations in the query planner's ability to infer relationships, unexpected correlations, or cost parameters like `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost` that don't match the real system.

Comment: @SneakyWombat **explain.depesz.com** please, avoids bloating the questions/answers with verbose query plans. What's with the double-quoting around those plans?

Comment: I'll add this index. It will take awhile though :( standby, also work_mem is set to 5000MB. The system is a quad E5520  @ 2.27GHz, yielding 16 cores. 8Gig of ram, raid 5, 1tb of storage.  I know raid 5 is bad for writes, but i'll only be querying this info, never writing new rows.

Comment: @SneakyWombat Hmm. The 1st estimates 1.4 million rows, the 2nd estimates 63 million rows. The 1st has a 10x higher cost estimate, though, so I'm not too sure which will be better. Looking at those plans I'm wondering what PostgreSQL version you're running on, and whether you're able to benefit from 9.2's index-only scans or not; it should be using an index-only scan to get the tagnames in 9.2.

Comment: sorry, didn't know about that site. i'll use that in the future.  thanks :D

Comment: I'm using 9.1.3. deal breaker?

Comment: @SneakyWombat RAID 5 isn't great for reads either :S and most importantly, if PostgreSQL has to spill to temporary files on disk for sorts your performance will be absolutely hosed to an amazing extent. `SET log_temp_files = 0` before running big queries (or set it in postgresql.conf) and see if it's using tempfiles for sorting. If it is, you might need to move your tempfile location to faster-writing storage. Also, the 16 cores won't do you any good, all this will run on a single core I'm afraid.

Comment: @SneakyWombat ... and 9.1.3 is fine, though 9.1.6 is fully compatible and you should think about upgrading as it contains some bug fixes. See the release notes for 9.1: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release.html . You might get a big boost from 9.2's index-only scans (http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgresql-9-2-highlight-index-only-scans/), but then ... you might not, too, and upgrading your big database will be a bit of a pain.

Comment: @SneakyWombat BTW, a quick test with `SET enable_seqscan = off` suggests that the index mentioned in my post should also benefit Clodoaldo's query, or at least can be used for it.

Comment: So far, @Clodoaldo seems to be the fastest, but using the complicated floor index you suggested. However, it returns two rows for each 15 min interval and i'm not sure why.  This is a vast improvement!  Very excited.

Comment: @SneakyWombat If you will never update those tables then just insert the result of the query into a summary table and query from there. No need to worry about optimizations.

Comment: Don't the optimizations help the query execute faster though?  I'm running the query over the entire dataset right now, it's been going for about 35 minutes.  Not sure how long it will take.  I appreciate the help!  I initially tried dumping this into a mysql database but that ended poorly rather quickly.  At about 2 billion records, the table auto-truncated itself. long live postgresql!