# Grouping based on every N days in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time, aggregation, window-functions

I have a table that includes ID, date, values (temperature) and some other stuff. My table looks like this:

```
+-----+--------------+------------+
| ID  |  temperature |    Date    |
+-----+--------------+------------+
|  1  |  26.3        | 2012-02-05 |
|  2  |  27.8        | 2012-02-06 |
|  3  |  24.6        | 2012-02-07 |
|  4  |  29.6        | 2012-02-08 |
+-----+--------------+------------+
```

I want to perform aggregation queries like sum and mean for every 10 days.

I was wondering if it is possible in psql or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "every 10 days?"  Do you want a moving window?  1-10, 2-11, 3-12, etc?  Or would 1-10, 11-20, and 21-31 be good enough?

Comment: I mean moving window. But if it is not really possible in psql I have to resort to the second option. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/822fb/1)

```
select
    "date",
    temperature,
    avg(temperature) over(order by "date" rows 10 preceding) mean
from t
order by "date"
```

Comment: Thank you Clodoaldo. Your solution works for me. But I also need to calculate them for every separate 10 days period. like calculating average first 10 days, second 10 days . . .

Comment: @user1043898 That's really a different question, but it's already well answered elsewhere. Use `group by extract(epoch from the_date) / extract(epoch from interval '10' day)` . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921598/efficiently-querying-a-huge-time-series-table-for-one-row-every-15-minutes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623358/group-by-data-intervals

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to perform the query. One explanation is that the records are for every day, and 10 day grouping can be done by grouping of every 10 IDs. But I don't know how to calculate every 10 records.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, 
       temperature, 
       sum(temperature) over (order by "date" rows between 10 preceding and current row)
from the_table;
```

It might not exactly be what you want, as it will do a moving sum over the last 10 rows, which is not necessarily the same as the last 10 days.

---

Since Postgres 11, you can now use a range based on an interval

```
select id, 
       temperature, 
       avg(temperature) over (order by "date" 
                                range between interval '10 days' preceding and current row)
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I mean, but I got this error:  ERROR:  frame starting from current row cannot have preceding rows

                                                             ^

Comment: @user1043898: sorry, got the limits mixed up. See my edit please.